# How can I enable Flutter/Dart language experiments?

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

I want to use the new [spread syntax](https://medium.com/dartlang/f1ccaf9f546c) in Dart.

I'm using Android Studio for Flutter development and I receive this error.

> This requires the --spread-collections experiment to be enabled

```
ListView(children: [...listTiles, MyWidget()])
```

However, I didn't find anywhere where I could specify this option.

I couldn't even make it work on the command line. `flutter --spread-collections run` gives `Could not find an option named "spread-collections".`.

```
flutter --version
Flutter 1.3.8 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e5b1ed7a7f (4 weeks ago) • 2019-03-06 14:23:37 -0800
Engine • revision f4951df193
Tools • Dart 2.2.1 (build 2.2.1-dev.0.0 571ea80e11)
```

Comment: You need to be on master branch

Comment: The experimental features are only on `master` branch. By default you are on `stable` branch. You can see channels using `flutter channel`. Read https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels for more info.

Comment: if you still can't get it to work, this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59458433/flutter-flow-control-collections-are-needed-but-are-they

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to create an analysis_options.yaml file in the root of your flutter app and write something like

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - spread-collections
```

Also make sure to switch to the correct channel where the new feature is included eg (dev, beta or master)

```
flutter channel dev
```

And also make sure you have a recent enough version of flutter

```
flutter upgrade
```

Ensure you are on the right version of flutter and dart that allows that feature by running

```
flutter --version
```

you may also have to manually change your pubspec.yaml file to specify the correct dart sdk (if so rerun flutter upgrade)

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0-0 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 24):

In my case, I have followed these two steps and It worked for me.

1. run "**flutter upgrade**"
2. changing the sdk in the environment in pubspec.yaml

   ```
   environment:
     sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
   ```

Comment: don't you need to change SDK first and then call "flutter upgrade"

Comment: Anyway, you need to remember to restart IDE

Answer (score 14):

With the new version of flutter it became an error - but it can easily be fixed by updating the sdk version:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

Just don't forget to restart VisualStudio Code or whatever IDE you're using.

Answer (score 4):

You are running an old version of flutter

Spreading is available starting at **flutter 1.5** and **dart 2.3**

Run:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks, please note I asked this questions in April, where Dart 2.3 was not yet available for Flutter in any channels.

Comment: also depends on which flutter channel you are

Answer (score 3):

Here's some fix you can try out :

1) Keep the analysis_options.yaml in your root folder with this code:

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - control-flow-collections
```

2) Don't use brackets {} in between your for loops
**Ex:**

```
<Widget>[
  for (final category in categories) 
    CategoryWidget(category: category)
],
```

**3) Important step which is probably why it's not working for you:**
Change your Dart version constraint in the pubspec.yml file in your root folder to 2.5.2 or above.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.5.2 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 3):

The current answer that is working in the latest Flutter 1.17.1 or Dart 2.8.2

Create a analysis_options.yaml in the directory of the pubspec.yaml file

Write this code inside the file:

```
include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.1.8.0.yaml 

linter:
  rules:
    - prefer_spread_collections
```

[For more information head to this documentation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/analysis_server/analysis_options.yaml)

Comment: I Tried it. But I am getting an error 'include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.1.8.0.yaml 
' file cannot be found.

Comment: @ShubhamBansal You need to add `pedantic: ^1.8.0` to your `dev_dependencies` in `pubspec.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

Something completely different yet the same. Our code was built in Flutter v1.12.13hotfix9. when we did a new installation with flutter 1.17.1 the build broke with a similar error. It seems that the new release of Flutter is not backwards compatible on certain parts. 
We fixed the problem by installing the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from your project's root directory:

```
dart --enable-experiment=spread-collections lib
```

Answer (score 0):

After updating the environment in pubspec.yml **don't forget restart your IDE**

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.2 <3.0.0"
```