# How to enable spread (...) operater in Flutter development

Tags: flutter, dart

I followed this: [How can I enable Flutter/Dart language experiments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477046/how-can-i-enable-flutter-dart-language-experiments)

However, the spread operator still does not work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run `flutter upgrade` from the terminal and then update your Dart version constraint in `pubspec.yaml`:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.5.2 <3.0.0'
```

The *spread operator* is not a language experiment anymore, hence, you do not need to *enable* any experiment.
Note that Dart `2.3.0` is the first version with the spread operator, however, at the time of writing `2.5.2` is already on the stable channel and should be your choice because of this.