# How to enable Null-Safety in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I tried to use null safety, but it's giving me this error:

> This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled. Try
> updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.10.0
> or higher, and running 'pub get'.

I changed my Dart SDK constraint from `2.7.0` to `2.10.0`, but it's still showing this error.

[image]

Also, I upgraded my Dart and Flutter SDK:

> dart-sdk v2.10.2 is the latest version available based on your
> source(s).
>
> Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, ...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To Enable null safety,

1. Check Latest Dart Version(It should be Dart 2.12 or later:)

   ```
   dart --version
   ```
2. Update the dart version, the above point not satisfied using the command.

   ```
   dart pub upgrade --null-safety

   dart pub get
   ```
3. Run the below command to know what are libs in your project needs to be upgraded to the latest null safety.

   ```
   dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety
   ```

The **latest** column shows the current version if it's in green that means dependency implemented null safety features if it red then the dependency owner needs to implement that.

[image]

4. Finally, run dart migration command which performs null safety migration on existing project(Existing project)

   ```
   dart migrate
   ```
5. If your package is ready to migrate, then the tool produces a line like the following:

   View the migration suggestions by visiting:

   http://127.0.0.1:60278/Users/you/project/mypkg.console-simple?authToken=Xfz0jvpyeMI%3D

**Note:** Even after running `upgrade --null-safety` command, you see the latest column section in red, which means a particular dependency hasn't supported null safety yet, so that means you cannot migrate the project.

for detail read: https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

Answer (score 74):

Null safety is *no longer an experiment* *as of* Dart `2.12`. It is now easy to enable.

#### Enabling null safety

Starting with the first Dart `2.12` versions, types will be **non-nullable by default**. So you just need to change your SDK constraint:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

---

Learn more about ["Enabling null safety" on dart.dev](https://dart.dev/null-safety#enable-null-safety).

Comment: It is now stable (Flutter 2.0.0)

Comment: Getting error: [chatflutter] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in chatflutter...                  
The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.0-133.7.beta.

Because chatflutter requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because chatflutter requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

Comment: @Kamlesh Please make sure to run `flutter upgrade` :) Dart 2.12.0 is available as of Flutter 2.0.0.

Comment: I have already developed the application and if I go with Dart 2.12 version with null safety feature then it will throw me back 10 days to solve all the issues are raised after applying Dart 2.12 version with null safety. BTW I have updated flutter version to 2.0.0 and made flutter ui changes in my app. I made a copy of my application and applied Dart 2.12 version then fixed Dart 2.12 updates related issues in my app and wasted 11-12 hours which was waste of time because many packages are not compatible with Dart 2.12 null safety feature, then I rolled back my application today. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dart is also saying that WAIT for the packages that you depend on to migrate, so not good to migrate to Dart 2.12 with null safety feature. https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

Comment: I think it's actually good to migrate as soon as you've got the green light, @Kamlesh . Like you said, _you just have to wait for your dependencies before doing so_. 

Answer (score 10):

After **Flutter 2.0.0** Stable u can run in app **root** folder:

```
dart migrate --apply-changes
```

Answer (score 6):

This can happen when you upgrade the Flutter version you're using.

Try adding the following to the analysis_options.yml

```
analyzer:
    - enable-experiment:
        - non-nullable
```

Then, try cleaning and upgrading the project dependencies again.
To do that, you can use the following commands:

```
flutter clean
flutter packages pub upgrade
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Finally, restart your IDE.

P.s. By the way, make sure that the sdk you're using is compatible with your Flutter version

Comment: do I must to import something?

Comment: Can you try restarting your ide?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62153557/10907417

Comment: @AbdallahEl-Rashedy This now does not require the `enable-experiment` anymore; see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65117431/6509751).

Answer (score 6):

Following the [Dart documentation](https://dart.dev/null-safety#enable-null-safety) I was able to enable null safety in Flutter with these steps:

First add `analysis_options.yaml`:

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - non-nullable
```

Then move to the dev channel and upgrade:

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
```

Change the sdk in `pubspec.yaml`

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0-213.0.dev <2.12.0"
```

Clean the project:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Restart the IDE (VS Code in my case).

And then it was working fine.

Comment: Now, NNBD is no longer an experiment. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65117431/6509751).

Answer (score 3):

1. Set the lower Dart SDK constraint to `2.12` in your `pubspec.yaml` file.

   ```
   environment:
     sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
   ```
2. Check if all the packages of your app are migrated to null safety.

   ```
   dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety
   ```
3. If they are migrated, update all the packages to their null safe variant.

   ```
   dart pub upgrade --null-safety 
   dart pub get
   ```
4. Start the migration process.

   ```
   dart migrate
   ```

   If you're happy with the changes, apply them using:

   ```
   dart migrate --apply-changes
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I had done all the above and yet for some reason the analyzer still gave an error about enabling null safety. What fixed it for me was running pub upgrade instead of pub get. I'm not even going to try to find out why, I'm just going to get back to work!

Comment: " I'm not even going to try to find out why, I'm just going to get back to work!" I am taking this as a  life lesson after trying to fix this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that evenIn 2022 it still works doing this...

Environment:
SDK: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: I am having exactly same issue, my Dart & Flutter are both on latest versions.  Pubspec.yaml is correct.  Android Studio has been restarted.  Flutter pub get has been run.