# Flutter null safety checks

Tags: flutter

flutter seems to be switching between null safety checks and nonnull safety checks causing dozens of issues.

Running: flutter clean remove all null check errors,
but when I run: flutter pub get the null errors return?

Really confusing, my dart sdk:

```
environment:sdk: ">=2.11.6 <3.0.0"
```

I think dart was updated recently to include null checks and it seems to be causing loads of problems for me, I have corrected the null errors before anyone suggests this and when I run flutter clean the null error check I have implemented cause errors.

```
lib/screens/add_new_location_note_screen.dart:23:8: 
Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.12 or higher. Place? _pickedLocation;
```

Now I have changed the minimum sdk to

```
environment: sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

ran: flutter clean

and the errors again disappear now running: flutter pub get

the null errors checks return ???

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66636686/5106574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the SDK constraints like so:

```
environment: sdk: ">=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0"
```

Currently, the 2.12 SDK is in pre-release (beta), requiring the use of the `-0` to signify the pre-release version to use.

Comment: I updated the answer to give a brief explanation of why this is required.