# I am not able to use the late keyword in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, dart

I thought that I had updated Android Studio to the latest version of Flutter/dart; however, I am unable to use any of the new features like the 'late' keyword as I can do in DartPad; please see the image below for an example.

[image]

I believe that I am currently up-to-date on updates, I've even re-installed Android Studio:

[image]

Question: Is there something that needs to be done to use all of the latest versions?

I am completely stumped here and any help would be appreciated. Also, I hope that this is an acceptable topic for discussion.

Comment: I have also found that this command works too: dart migrate --apply-changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `late` keyword is a feature of null safety. You will need to migrate your project. If it is a new project, it can be as simple as running `dart migrate` in the project dir and accepting all changes. If you have an existing project, you may need to do more.

Further details here: https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Stephen, I also found this link for being useful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64621051/how-to-enable-null-safety-in-flutter