# How to Iterate through nested json object array

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am very new to Json parsing.
I have to iterate throught json array object.

**my JSON class:**

```
  class Jsons {
  static var hotelListJson = {
    'hotelData': [
      {
        'index': 0,
        'restaurantName': 'Monginis Cake Shop',
        'foodCategory': 'The Cake Shop',
        'restReview': 5,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant1.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 40,
        'restStatus': 'open',
        'menuCategories': [
          {
            'categoryName': 'Pastry',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Dutch Pastry',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Black Forest pastry',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Truffle Pastry',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Dutch Alond Veg',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },

          {
            'categoryName': 'Breads',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Sandwich Bread',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Multigrain Bread',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Duth Chocolate Heart Veg (Small)',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Brown Bread',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },

          
          {
            'categoryName': 'Savouries',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Panner pattice',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Veg Burger',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Pan Pizza Veg',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Veg pattice',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        'index': 1,
        'restaurantName': 'Swami Hotel',
        'foodCategory': 'Family Hotel',
        'restReview': 2,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant2.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 40,
        'restStatus': 'open',
        'menuCategories': [
          {
            'categoryName': 'Veg Starter',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Paneer pahadi kabab',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Garlic chana',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Masala papad',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Manchurian',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Masroom chilli',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'categoryName': 'Non Veg Starter',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'CHI Chilli Gravy',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Lollypop Sezwan',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Pan Pizza Veg',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken crispy',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Mandeli fry',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'categoryName': 'Tandoori',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Tandoori',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Tangadi Kabab',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Pahadi Kabab',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Hydrabadi Kabab',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Mutton Kadhai',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
          
          {
            'categoryName': 'NON VEG SOUP',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Chi manchaow Soup',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chi Clear Soup',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chi Schezwan Soup',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Swami Special Chi Soup',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'categoryName': 'VEG SOUP',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Masala',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Tikka Masala',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Handi',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Butter Chicken',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Mutton Kadhai',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        'index': 2,
        'restaurantName': 'Smart open pick cake shop',
        'foodCategory': 'Cake Shop',
        'restReview': 1,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant4.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 10,
        'restStatus': 'closed',
        'offer': 'Get 5% discount',
        'menuCategories': [
          {
            'categoryName': 'CAKE HALF Kg',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Black Forest',
                'price': 300,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Pineapple half kg',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Lichi half kg',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'choco chips half kg',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'categoryName': 'CAKE 1 KG',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Butterscotch',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Rose falooda',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'White forest ovenpick',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Mix Fruit',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        'index': 3,
        'restaurantName': 'Mitarth Chinese',
        'foodCategory': 'Chinese corner',
        'restReview': 3,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant5.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 20,
        'restStatus': 'open',
      },
      {
        'index': 4,
        'restaurantName': 'Selfie Chat',
        'foodCategory': 'Paani Puri & more',
        'restReview': 2,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant6.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 40,
        'restStatus': 'open',
      },
      {
        'index': 5,
        'restaurantName': 'Gareeb Nawaj Biryani',
        'foodCategory': 'Caterers Biryani',
        'restReview': 5,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant7.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 40,
        'restStatus': 'open',
      },
      {
        'index': 6,
        'restaurantName': 'Prem Sweets',
        'foodCategory': 'Sweets shop',
        'restReview': 1,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant8.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 40,
        'restStatus': 'closed',
        'offer': 'Get 5% discount',
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

Basically what I am doing is abc is name of a hotel and the list of subCategory that abc has are populated inside it.also subCategory has list of type.

The problem is there can be many Types under that hotel. So i need a proper looping structure in Dart that can be generic to handle it.

I have successfully parse the main Array but I cannot parse the subCaterory and type under subcategory.

This is How I iterate:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < (Jsons.hotelListJson['hotelData'].length); i++) {
      var currObj = Jsons.hotelListJson['hotelData'][i];
      var currObjSubCategoryList =
          currObj['menuCategories'] as List<Map<String, Object>>;
      for (int j = 0; j < currObjSubCategoryList.length; j++) {
        var listItem = currObjSubCategoryList[j];
        var typeList = listItem['categoryName'] as List<Map<String, Object>>;
        for (int k = 0; k < typeList.length; k++) {
          var temp = typeList[k];
          var currTypeName = temp['dishes'];
          print(currTypeName);
          restaurantListModel.add(RestaurantListModel(
            currObj['restaurantName'],
            currObj['foodCategory'],
            currObj['restReview'],
            currObj['restImage'],
            currObj['distanceFromLocation'],
            currObj['restStatus'],
          ));
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is my Model class:

```
class RestaurantListModel {
  var name,
      category,
      review,
      offer;
  final List<String> menuCategory;

  RestaurantListModel(
      this.restaurantName,
      this.foodCategory,
      this.restReview,
      this.restImage,
      this.distanceFromLocation,
      this.restStatus,
      this.menuCategory,
      {this.offer});

}
```

my Container:

```
Container(
              //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 450,
              child: NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification>(
                onNotification: (overscroll) {
                  overscroll.disallowGlow();
                },
                child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10, bottom: 30, left: 15, right: 15),
                    controller: ScrollController(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: restaurantListModel.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return RestaurantCard(restaurantListModel, index,
                          restaurantListModel[index]);
                    }),
              ),
            )
```

In RestaurantCard class :
this is how i display data :

```
              Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      widget.restaurantListModelObj.restaurantName,
                      style: commonTextStyle(
                          size: 2.4 * SizeConfig.textMultiplier,
                          whichFont: 'bold'),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      widget.restaurantListModelObj.foodCategory,
                      style: commonTextStyle(
                        size: 2 * SizeConfig.textMultiplier,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Please HELP

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if type is a list, it has a length property right, you can just do ```hotelListJson[`myData`][i][`subCategory'][j]['type'][k]``` and you can use `map()` function with 'type' array

Comment: can you please explain your answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant by iterating over the length of the lists, I have added a code from where you can get an idea of how you can parse.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
class Jsons {
  static var hotelListJson = {
    'hotelData': [
      {
        'index': 0,
        'restaurantName': 'Monginis Cake Shop',
        'foodCategory': 'The Cake Shop',
        'restReview': 5,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant1.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 40,
        'restStatus': 'open',
        'menuCategories': [
          {
            'categoryName': 'Pastry',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Dutch Pastry',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Black Forest pastry',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Truffle Pastry',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Dutch Alond Veg',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'categoryName': 'Breads',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Sandwich Bread',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Multigrain Bread',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Duth Chocolate Heart Veg (Small)',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Brown Bread',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'categoryName': 'Savouries',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Panner pattice',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Veg Burger',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Pan Pizza Veg',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Veg pattice',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        'index': 1,
        'restaurantName': 'Swami Hotel',
        'foodCategory': 'Family Hotel',
        'restReview': 2,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant2.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 40,
        'restStatus': 'open',
        'menuCategories': [
          {
            'categoryName': 'Veg Starter',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Paneer pahadi kabab',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Garlic chana',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Masala papad',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Manchurian',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Masroom chilli',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'categoryName': 'Non Veg Starter',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'CHI Chilli Gravy',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Lollypop Sezwan',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Pan Pizza Veg',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken crispy',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Mandeli fry',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'categoryName': 'Tandoori',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Tandoori',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Tangadi Kabab',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Pahadi Kabab',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Hydrabadi Kabab',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Mutton Kadhai',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'categoryName': 'NON VEG SOUP',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Chi manchaow Soup',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chi Clear Soup',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chi Schezwan Soup',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Swami Special Chi Soup',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'categoryName': 'VEG SOUP',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Masala',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Tikka Masala',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Chicken Handi',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Butter Chicken',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Mutton Kadhai',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        'index': 2,
        'restaurantName': 'Smart open pick cake shop',
        'foodCategory': 'Cake Shop',
        'restReview': 1,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant4.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 10,
        'restStatus': 'closed',
        'offer': 'Get 5% discount',
        'menuCategories': [
          {
            'categoryName': 'CAKE HALF Kg',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Black Forest',
                'price': 300,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Pineapple half kg',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Lichi half kg',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'choco chips half kg',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'categoryName': 'CAKE 1 KG',
            'dishes': [
              {
                'dishName': 'Butterscotch',
                'price': 5,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Rose falooda',
                'price': 50,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'White forest ovenpick',
                'price': 35,
              },
              {
                'dishName': 'Mix Fruit',
                'price': 50,
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        'index': 3,
        'restaurantName': 'Mitarth Chinese',
        'foodCategory': 'Chinese corner',
        'restReview': 3,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant5.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 20,
        'restStatus': 'open',
      },
      {
        'index': 4,
        'restaurantName': 'Selfie Chat',
        'foodCategory': 'Paani Puri & more',
        'restReview': 2,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant6.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 40,
        'restStatus': 'open',
      },
      {
        'index': 5,
        'restaurantName': 'Gareeb Nawaj Biryani',
        'foodCategory': 'Caterers Biryani',
        'restReview': 5,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant7.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 40,
        'restStatus': 'open',
      },
      {
        'index': 6,
        'restaurantName': 'Prem Sweets',
        'foodCategory': 'Sweets shop',
        'restReview': 1,
        'restImage': 'assets/images/Restaurant8.png',
        'distanceFromLocation': 40,
        'restStatus': 'closed',
        'offer': 'Get 5% discount',
      }
    ]
  };
}

void main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < (Jsons.hotelListJson['hotelData']!.length); i++) {
    var currObj = Jsons.hotelListJson['hotelData']![i];
    if (currObj.containsKey('menuCategories')) {
          var currObjSubCategoryList =
        currObj['menuCategories'] as List<Map<String, Object>>;
      for (int j = 0; j < currObjSubCategoryList.length; j++) {
        var listItem = currObjSubCategoryList[j];
        var typeList = listItem['dishes']! as List<Map<String, Object>>;
        for (int k = 0; k < typeList.length; k++) {
          var temp = typeList[k];
          var currDishName = temp['dishName'];
          var currDishPrice = temp['price'];
          print("Name: " +
              currDishName.toString() +
              "\n" +
              " Price :" +
              currDishPrice.toString());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: it show me `The method 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.` this error for j loop

Comment: now it showing `The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length` error and i am not even iterate to main array.

Comment: I added complete code now, I have shown the output on DartPad as well

Comment: getting error `This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.12.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.` tried evrything, bt nothing working for me

Comment: it work perfectly correct on dartpad but not in my VS code

Comment: looks like you haven't added null safety

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64621051/how-to-enable-null-safety-in-flutter

Comment: the reason why you cannot integrate it onto VSCode is because your project doesn't have null safety. Just remove the `!`, `!.` from my code, and you should be able to integrate it onto VScode. Do you want me to remove null safety from my code?

Comment: when I add null safety in my code. it still showing the same error. and when i remove `!` it showing `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, Object>>' in type cast
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232153/discussion-between-tharun-k-and-shivani).

Answer (score 0):

You shoulkd use the primitive Object.entries and Object.keys everytime you want to examine a node.

I'll leave a short example here:

```js
const hotelListJSON = {
    "myData":
        [
            {
                'index':0,
                'name':'abc',
                'category':'ab',
                'review':5,
                'subCategory':
                [
                {
                 'catName': 'ab1',
                 'type':
                 [
                     {
                     'typeName':'t1',
                     'price':50,
                     }, 
                     {
                     'typeName':'t2',
                     'price':50,
                     }, 
                     {
                     'typeName':'t3',
                     'price':50,
                     }, 
                 ]
               }
               ]
            },
            
            {
                'index':1,
                'name':'abc1',
                'category':'dc',
                'review':5,
                'subCategory':
                [
                {
                 'catName': 'dc1',
                 'type':
                 [
                     {
                     'typeName':'dc',
                     'price':50,
                     }, 
                     {
                     'typeName':'dc',
                     'price':50,
                     }, 
                     {
                     'typeName':'dc',
                     'price':50,
                     }, 
                ]
                }
                ]
            },
        ]
     };
    };
    
    Object.keys(hotelListJSON).forEach((elem)=>{
      //here you have your first node
      console.log(elem);
      Object.keys(elem).forEach((elem2)=>{
      //here you have any object that is a nested object with its containing, if it is a simble element you just get the value
      console.log(elem2);
      )}
      })
```

With this script you can go as deep as you want.

Tell me if you encounter any problem.

Have a nice day.