# how to update flutterfire_web_sdk_version and how to enable 'non-nullable' language feature

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run my code, then I get this warning:

```
Flutter Web Bootstrap: Programmatic
            WARNING: FlutterFire for Web is explicitly tested against Firebase JS SDK version "8.10.1"
            but you are currently specifying "8.6.1" by either the imported Firebase JS SDKs in your web/index.html
            file or by providing an override - this may lead to unexpected issues in your application. It is recommended that you change all of the versions of the
            Firebase JS SDK version "8.10.1":

            If you override the version manually:
              change:
                <script>window.flutterfire_web_sdk_version = '8.6.1';</script>
              to:
                <script>window.flutterfire_web_sdk_version = '8.10.1';</script>

            If you import the Firebase scripts in index.html, instead allow FlutterFire to manage this for you by removing
            any Firebase scripts in your web/index.html file:
                e.g. remove: <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

I already tried to find `the <script>window.flutterfire_web_sdk_version = '8.6.1';</script>` in the index file, but I can't find it. Therefore I couldn't upgrade it.

Does someone know how to fix this warning?

**second question:**

When I want to use non-nullable, then I get this error:

```
This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
```

I am using `sdk: '>=2.6.0 <3.0.0'` so it should actually be enabled. Does someone know why it isn't working/enabled?

packages that i am using are (maybe this helps you):

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  responsive_builder: ^0.4.2
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  provider: ^4.1.1
  provider_architecture: ^1.1.1+1
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.19
  firebase_core: ^1.17.1
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.13
```

I already tried to `clean flutter` and using `Pug get` again.

Answer (score 2):

Second question:

For null safety you need to use `sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64621051/how-to-enable-null-safety-in-flutter) you can find how to enable null safety.